# what is the most optimal way of using location in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

If I am trying to create a location based recommender system in Django and where to start, Thanks in advance for answering this silly question

Comment: https://realpython.com/location-based-app-with-geodjango-tutorial/ Here see step by step how to use `GeoDjango`.

Answer (score 0):

**Accessing Locaton**

You can do it with `GeoDjango`. GeoDjango is used to access location of User, it's like a map in django. You can put or find a location of wherever you want.

**Gathering Data**

After that you can collect all the data of specific location in the single page. For example :- If user's location is 'Egypt` then gather users from Egypt.